# Diagonal morphism and zero

Tags: category-theory

Is true that in an additive category an object is a zero object iff the diagonal morphism is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true.  In an additive category matrix representations of maps between biproducts works.  So the diagonal map for an object $X$ can be represented by the matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1_X \\ 1_X \end{smallmatrix}\right]$.  The inverse of this will be of the form $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ for some $a, b \in \mathrm{Mor}(X, X)$ and then the equation $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1_X \\ 1_X \end{smallmatrix}\right]\left[\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \end{smallmatrix}\right] = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1_X & 0 \\ 0 & 1_X \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ allows you to conclude $1_X = 0$, which proves that $X$ is a zero object.

If you're uncomfortable with matrix representations of morphisms, everything I've written above can be phrased using just the universal properties of a biproduct and it would be a good exercise for you to translate the argument into that language.